# Can you deallocate memory with Go garbage collection disabled?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, go

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation

There is a way to allocate memory, but I don't see a way to deallocate memory (without the Go GC turned on).

If I wanted to write an OS using Go, I would need to either write a low level GC for Go or disable the Go GC. In the latter case, how could I free memory?

PS - this topic has been talked about extensively on the Go mailing list, but I wanted to pose this specific question to SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can free arbitrary memory by making [`runtime·free`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/malloc.goc?name=go1.1.2#128) accessible to your program
using cgo.

Build your own package called, for example, `mem` and create two files:

#### mem.go

```
package mem

import "unsafe"
import "reflect"

func FreePtr(p unsafe.Pointer)

func Free(v interface {}) {
    FreePtr(unsafe.Pointer(reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().Pointer()))
}
```

#### runtime.c

```
// +build gc
#include <runtime.h>

void ·Free(void* foo) {
    runtime·free(foo);
}
```

Example usage (free a slice and print number of frees):

```
import "free/mem"

func main() {
    var m1, m2 runtime.MemStats

    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m1)
    c := make([]int, 10000)
    inspect.Free(&c)
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m2)

    fmt.Printf("%d vs %d\n", m1.Frees, m2.Frees)
}
```

You should see that there was one more free than before.

Comment: I've considered this before and it makes sense. I can't find any current runtime function equivalents, so I'll accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: What is the special character in `runtime·free(void *v)`?

Comment: The middle dot is used in the C code of the runtime and other internal places to denote the package association of functions. C does not know packages so the dot is a way to bring packages to the Go C compiler. `runtime·free(void *v)` means that `free` belongs to package `runtime`.

Comment: curious, how would I type that dot character?

Comment: nvm, on ubuntu it's ctrl+shift+u and then '00b7' and then space. It's the Unicode mid dot character. Thanks.

Comment: The '·' character is used in C and assembler instead of a '.', since '.' isn't legal in an identifier in C.  You'll see if you disassemble a go binary (with objdump -d) that the all the '·'s are written as '.' in the binary.